# TheAfterWord does not take parameters after {

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run [this Spark example](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read#sort-merge_join_example) in InteliJ. However, the compiler complains about the `after` keyword:

> TheAfterWord does not take parameters after {

Code Summary:

```
class SortMergeJoinSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Sort-merge join test")
.master("local[*]")
.config("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", "true")
.config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "1")
.config("spark.sql.defaultSizeInBytes", "100000")
.getOrCreate()

  after {
    sparkSession.stop()
  }

  "sort-merge join" should "be used when neither broadcast nor hash join are possible" in {
    ... bla bla bla
  }

  "for not sortable keys the sort merge join" should "not be used" in {
    ... bla bla bla
  }

  private def toAssertRowInterval(row: Row): String = {
    ... bla bla bla
  }

  private def toAssertRow(row: Row): String = {
    ... bla bla bla
  }
}
```

Full code: [Sort-merge join example](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read#sort-merge_join_example)

Maybe the problem is related to the class definition. They don't have a class definition in the example so I had to add it by myself.

Comment: `class SortMergeJoinSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh thanks. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sarvesh Kumar Singh commented, I had to declare the class like that:

```
class SortMergeJoinSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter {
```